# HTML helpers throw exception on accessing property when dbnull

Tags: model-view-controller, strongly-typed-dataset

I just upgraded my project to ASP.net MVC RC. The bad thing is HTML helpers are throwing exceptions from the dataset even when I pass a new datarow. Error is as a result of conversion to dbnull from .net object types.

This exceptions occurs on my UI. I do check for DBnull on update but not when binding. MVC beta wasn't behaving as such and I think it's good. Frameworks shouldn't throw exceptions on retrieving dbnull values from datasource...

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the values in your dataset to a view model, a collection of objects of a class with strongly-typed, named properties corresponding to your columns, that contains `null` values instead of `DBNull`.  Pass this model to your view.
2. Report the problem at [www.codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/WorkItem/List.aspx) as an issue.  Note you may need to create a free login before you can submit an issue.

Comment: datatables doesnt support nullable object...doing this for all > 20 tables would be reengineering...i'll rather use Entity frameworks if that is the case...my question is, why with MVC RC?